# how do you obtain a member of a class which is also a member of a class of the same type?

Tags: c++

I'm currently writing a program in c++ using recursion and I want to print out a vector of tuples that resides in a class member which has the same type as the class itself. Below, you can see the class "Data" which has a class member called "child" of the same type. It also has a vector of tuples I want to print out using the readTuples function.

```
class Data {
    public:
        vector<tuple<string, string, string>> myTuple;
        Data *child;

    void readTuples(){
        for (int i = 0; i < myTuple.size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout << "ID: " << get<0>(myTuple[i]) << "\tTYPE: " << get<1>(myTuple[i]) << "\tVALUE: " << get<2>(myTuple[i]) << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

In the function below, I receive the Data object as a parameter. I add a child to the Data object using the typecheck function which returns a data object with a filled vector of tuples. I then read the vector using the readTuples function. This works...

```
 Data typecheck(Data data)
{
    Data* child = new Data();
    Data childData = statementList->typecheck(*child);
    child = &childData;
    data.child = child;
    data.child->readTuples();
    return data;
}
```

> output
> ID: a   TYPE: integer   VALUE: 1
> ID: b   TYPE: integer   VALUE: 2
> ID: c   TYPE: integer   VALUE: 3

The data object is then returned and caught in the object Data (i.e. the typecheck function has just been executed).

```
Data typecheck(Data data)
{
    data = block->typecheck(data);
    data.child->readTuples();
    
    return data;
}
```

But when I try to read the vector of tuples again, it crashes. The command line returns weird symbols, so I presume this has something to do with pointers and memory allocation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Warning: `Data typecheck(Data data)` a lot of pass by value here. Copies will be made, copies will be edited, and copies will be returned. Not enough context here to be sure that this is what you want or need, but I recommend making sure it's the behaviour you want before going much further.

Comment: Yes memory allocation. The problem is that you aren't doing any. Since you want `child` to outlive the function `typecheck` you should allocate it with `new`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Data typecheck(Data data)
{
    Data* child = new Data();
    Data childData = statementList->typecheck(*child);
    child = &childData;
    data.child = child;
    data.child->readTuples();
    return data;
}
```

`childData` is a local variable whose reference you take. Once this function terminates, `childData` is destroyed, and any references to it invalidated. At that point, `data.child` points to garbage, and dereferencing it is undefined behavior.

If you want the pointer to last longer than the current function, either return it, or allocate it on the heap and store a pointer to *that*.

Comment: As a bonus dash of wound-salt, the original object acquired with `Data *child = new Data();` is leaked into the ether. And I suspect the alternate ctors, and dtor, of `Data` won't be doing the OP any favors either, especially with that naked `child` pointer member. The OP seems to be of the belief that C++ pointer/reference mechanics are similar to Java or C#.